# I need help animating the trajectory of a body in space

Tags: python, matplotlib-animation

I'm working on a 3-body system and I'm trying to animate their trajectory. I have already made the graphs that show their trajectory at the end of the specified steps. Furthermore, I tried to animate the trajectory but didn't work.

I used FuncAnimation(), as shown in the code, but it only displays an empty graph and no animation shows. I'm not really sure what the reason is exactly.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#Inital Conditions
y0 = [-1        ,#x1
  0             ,#y1
  1             ,#x2
  0             ,#y2
  0             ,#x3
  0             ,#y3
  0.306893      ,#vx1
  0.125507      ,#vy1
  0.306893      ,#vx2
  0.125507      ,#vy2
  -2*0.306893   ,#vx3
  -2*0.125507]   #vy3

# Time steps and the total number of steps
N = 10000
T = 0.001 

#Definition of the Function 
def ThreeBody(t,y):
   f = np.zeros(12)

  # The velocities of the three bodies
   f[0] = y[6]
   f[1] = y[7]
   f[2] = y[8]
   f[3] = y[9]
   f[4] = y[10]
   f[5] = y[11]

  # The x and y positions of each object respectively
   f[6] = -(y[0]-y[2])/(((y[0]-y[2])**2+(y[1]-y[3])**2)**(3/2)) \
        -(y[0]-y[4])/(((y[0]-y[4])**2+(y[1]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
        
   f[7] = -(y[1]-y[3])/(((y[0]-y[2])**2+(y[1]-y[3])**2)**(3/2)) \
        -(y[1]-y[5])/(((y[0]-y[4])**2+(y[1]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
                  
   f[8] = -(y[2]-y[0])/(((y[2]-y[0])**2+(y[3]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
        -(y[2]-y[4])/(((y[2]-y[4])**2+(y[3]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
        
   f[9] = -(y[3]-y[1])/(((y[2]-y[0])**2+(y[3]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
        -(y[3]-y[5])/(((y[2]-y[4])**2+(y[3]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
                  
   f[10]= -(y[4]-y[0])/(((y[4]-y[0])**2+(y[5]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
        -(y[4]-y[2])/(((y[4]-y[2])**2+(y[5]-y[3])**2)**(3/2))
        
   f[11]= -(y[5]-y[1])/(((y[4]-y[0])**2+(y[5]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
        -(y[5]-y[3])/(((y[4]-y[2])**2+(y[5]-y[3])**2)**(3/2))

   return f


#Solving for the positions of all bodies
t = np.linspace(0,N*T,N)
solution = solve_ivp(ThreeBody,[0,800],y0,t_eval=t,rtol=1e-12)


#Evolution in Position with respect to Time
plt.plot(solution.y[0],solution.y[1],'-g') #Positions body 1
plt.plot(solution.y[2],solution.y[3],'-r') #Positions body 2
plt.plot(solution.y[4],solution.y[5],'-b') #Positions body 3
plt.ylabel("Position(y)")
plt.xlabel("Position(x)")
plt.show()

plt.plot(t,solution.y[0])
plt.ylabel("Position (x)")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1.5, 1.5), ylim=(-0.5, 0.5))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def animate(n):
    line.set_xdata(solution.y[0])
    line.set_ydata(solution.y[1])
    return line,


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames= 1000, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you been able to display any other animation with `FuncAnimation` so far at all?

Comment: It's really my first time trying to animate something. I have downloaded ffmpeg if that is why you are asking. Do I have to download something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

[image]

Make sure you're using Python 3.10 or later.

**Step 1: install NumPy with**

```
   pip3 install Numpy
```

**Step 2: run the file**

```
   python3 test.py
```

You may want to import the animate() function too:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1.5, 1.5), ylim=(-0.5, 0.5))
lines = [ax.plot([], [], lw=2) for _ in range(3)]
def animate(n):
  lines[0][0].set_data(solution.y[0][:n], solution.y[1][:n])
  lines[1][0].set_data(solution.y[2][:n], solution.y[3][:n])
  lines[2][0].set_data(solution.y[4][:n], solution.y[5][:n])
  return lines[0][0], lines[1][0], lines[2][0],

  anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000, interval=10, blit=True)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: I see now how the function works. The plot appears, but it's just blank. I have tried tweaking the frame and interval but didn't work.

Comment: where are you running the code? Jupyter? Local?

Comment: if your using Jupiter you need to do something like: HTML(anim.to_html5_video())

Comment: Please review *"[How to use you're and your](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-You%27re-and-Your)"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I will not lol..im dyslexic and ppl like you try to give me a hard time all my life...im still doing great as a Sr Solution Architect )....your welcome hahahah